# XCode Color Discrepancy

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode seems to be displaying two colors for the same RGB, Hex code, and opacity. Screenshot of color picker and button attached below: the left and right are slightly differing colors. Why is this discrepancy happening?

RGB: (211, 84, 63)

Hex: D3543F

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between the screenshots? Is it the same button, or are they two buttons of the same color?

Comment: They're juxtaposed screenshots of the same button showing two varying colors. These colors show up on my recently used colors in storyboard.

Comment: Click on the gear in the color pick and make sure they are using the same color profile.

Comment: So, you change your button's color between two different entrie of the Most Recently Used list, which happen to have the exact same RGB values, but somewhow look different? What does the Digital Color Meter app tell you when you hover the cursor over 1. The button in each case, and 2. Each color's  swatches in the MRU list?

Comment: Both colors are using the same color profile. Digital Color Meter says that the color on the left is (199, 62, 49) and the color on the right is (211, 83, 63). Why would XCode be unable to distinguish between the two?

Comment: One of the buttons is custom and the other one is system? Open the storyboard xml and show us the difference.

Comment: It's the same, default UIButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a recent case like this on OSX. One of the colors was in the NSCalibratedRGB color space, and the other was in the device color space. Not sure how you'd get a calibrated color into the color picker's recently-used list, but that could be it. The RGB values in the color picker will be the same, but the cooor meter will show them as different.

Comment: Yep, this exactly. I had the same issue and it can be frustrating to diagnose and fix. Click on the cog icon to the right of the "RGB Sliders" drop-down to reveal the colour profiles being used. Selecting a different profile will slightly change a colour shown for a given RGB value. This doesn't change the colour profile for the whole app, just for that specific colour you chose. Good luck

Comment: Excellent point on using the cog icon to check the color space.